# Context issues with React and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: reactjs, three.js, components, requestanimationframe

I'm currently playing around with React and Three.js. I'm trying to call an update function that is passed as a prop to another component as below. The problem is I get an error sayign `this.cube` is undefined.

```js
 public renderer : THREE.WebGLRenderer;
  public scene : THREE.Scene = new THREE.Scene();
  public camera : THREE.PerspectiveCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 400 / 300, 0.1, 0.1);
  public cube : THREE.Mesh;

  public componentDidMount() {
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(this.cube);
  }

     public update = () => {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.cube);
        this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      }

      public render() {

        const sceneArr : THREE.Scene[] = [];
        sceneArr.push(this.scene);

        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Three mainCamera={this.camera} width={400} height={300} update={this.update} scenes={sceneArr} />
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }

Here is the render function inside the `Three` component calling `requestAnimationFrame`.

      public threeRender = () => {
        this.props.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(this.threeRender);
        this.props.scenes.forEach(scene => {
          this.renderer.render(scene, this.props.mainCamera);
        });
      }
```

I assumed that the context of `this` inside `update` was incorrectly referring to the `Three` component, but it turns out that the print statements inside `update` showed contradicting evidence.

`console.log(this)` returns the correct object context, and the cube member shows up in the log, but `console.log(this.cube)` returns undefined. This makes no sense to me. Any ideas?

Comment: How is `cube` declared?

Comment: @SungKim i updated the code. After further investigation I think the problem is that the `Three` component mounts before `App` and is therefore referring to props that haven't been passed yet... I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of your `constructor` initialize `cube` and then you should be able to refer to it without getting that error.

```
constructor(props){
   this.cube = {}
}
```

Now you can give `this.cube` a value and refer to it from within `update()`

Comment: No worries, the error told me that the problem was that `this.cube` couldn't be found which usually means it's not defined or it's not bound to `this`

Comment: Yeah I incorrectly assumed that `componentDidMount` on the `App` component would be mounted before `Three`. I got confused because the props were still being passed down to `Three` which is actually expected behavior.